# -[CBPeripheral isConnected]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ios9, state, cbperipheral

I am developing an iPhone app that connects to a wristband, the Empatica E4, over bluetooth. This wristband gives you heart rate, perspiration etc. data.

Before upgrading to iOS 9.2 and Xcode 7, everything was fine. I was able to connect to the wristband from the iPhone and I was able to get data fine. However, after the upgrade, I started getting the following exception thrown once the iPhone connects to the wristband:

```
-[CBPeripheral isConnected]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I made my research and found out that the `isConnected` property is deprecated and the `state` property should be used instead:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CBPeripheral/isConnected

However, I don't use the `isConnected` property anywhere in my code. I also connected to the manufacturer of the wristband and apparently they don't use it either.

At this point, I am kind of hopeless. I was wondering if anybody came across this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party library or something that could possibly not yet be updated? Add a breakpoint for this to see where it is being used.

Comment: @WrightsCS, I just downloaded the sample project from the wristband manufacturer website and I have this issue. Thus, no 3rd party library. The exception is thrown once the iPhone discovers the wristband.

Answer (score 1):

I did the change.

`[peripheral isConnected]`

Became

`peripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You need to add a category to CBPeripheral that restores the isConnected method.

```
#import "CBPeripheral+APIFix.h"

@implementation CBPeripheral (APIFix)

-(BOOL)isConnected {
    if (self.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

@end
```